# How to hide the details of Soap address from the consumers of Web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have just started learning Web service(metro implementation) and I will be having one doubt as describe below -

```
<service name="PurchaseAppService">
<port name="PurchaseAppPort" binding="tns:PurchaseAppPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://xxxxx:8088/WebStore/PurchaseAppService"/>
</port>
</service>
```

If I provide this web service to the consumers in such  a way then in future if I would deploy the service on different container then again I have to share the contract with the consumers , So is there any way I can make it independent for the change in internal server address. I mean if for any change in the address location need not to share the contract again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the wsdl and replace the value in the location attribute by "BASE_URL_WS" or like before sending it to your consumers.
I have rarely seen this practice. In the facts, often, the WSDL is sent such as generated.
The provider of the wsdl has the responsibility to give the location url to his  clients for each existing and valid environment where the WS is deployed.
And the client has the responsibility to use the correct URL according to the target environment. Generally, from the client side, the URL location should be configured outside the packaged application (external file , database, etc...) in order that any WS URL change be easy to handle.